# WebDav clients does not cache credentials and no longer authenticate after 1 day

Tags: windows-server-2019, webdav

I have set this WebDav server under IIS for a few users located in different geographical locations that need to share the same folders. For each user there is a system user created and the authentication is set to Windows Authentication only. The server is using an SSL certificate using Let's Encrypt.

The server has a subdomain allocated exclusively to it similar to *dav.domain.com*. This subdomain does not serve other purpose than the WebDav. Also the IP is fixed for this server.

Each user is using his own username and password to access folders using the Add Network Location tool.

The problem resides in the fact that once the folder is added it is working as intended with the proper permissions set. After 1 day or so the server will ask for the password of the user. The pass is introduced but the server no longer authenticates the user. If I delete the network location and add it again it works as intended.

I tried to figure out the situation and found [this resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/credentials-prompt-access-webdav-fqdn-sites) that basically says a new registry entry should be created for the specific domain(s) for which Microsoft will cache the user and pass since the network location is not local. I have set the registry to both **.domain.com* and *dav.domain.com* but the issue persists.

The server is running Windows Server 2019.